# Java: Telling whether a byte array is a zip file

Tags: java, zip

I have a server written in Java, that in a single request, gets a whole file from the client. The file is passed to the server as a list of bytes, and is finally represented in the java server as a byte array.

Is there some standard way / standard library that could tell whether a file represented by a byte array is a valid **zip** file?

Comment: Look at its [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)).

Comment: What is your definition of a "valid zip file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are typically identified using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) in the beginning of the file.

To make an educated guess about a given file Java has built-in method of detecting some file types: [Files.probeContentType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-). Plus, there are various third party libraries: [simplemagic](https://github.com/j256/simplemagic) or [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) (which supports more than only magic numbers).

But content detection alone won't tell you whether the file is *valid*. For that, you'd need something that actually knows how to read Zip files, such as Java's [ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check [Zip4j](http://javadox.com/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.3.1/net/lingala/zip4j/core/ZipFile.html) library. It is really easy to use and the `ZipFile` class has a `isValidZipFile()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to standard way to implement for this process, you can use serialization API.For that use following articles that found myself while searching about this topic.

[Article 1 - javaworld](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html)
[Article 2 - developer.com](https://www.developer.com/java/data/advanced-concepts-of-java-object-serialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check the "PK" magic at the beginning of the byte array.

Something like this:

"PK".equals(new String(array, 0,2))